# How to set 'textbox.Text' value in placeholder on User Control Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, placeholder

I created dynamic textbox in placeholder. I set textboxID but I want to set `textbox.Text` value for each textbox while texbox(es) are creating.

User select how many create textbox on `ddlUserSelected` dropdownlist  whatever want. 
For example:
user select 3 on dropdownlist I create 3 textbox but I want to set each `textbox.text` value.

This is my code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUserSelected" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlUserSelected_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
 <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
 <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click"/>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void ddlUserSelected_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     for (int a = 1; a <= int.Parse(ddlUserSelected.SelectedItem.Text); a++)
            {

                TextBox txtDate = new TextBox();
                Label lbl = new Label();          
                lbl.Text = "<br/>";        
                txtDate .Width = 70;
                txtDate .CssClass = "tbl";
                txtDate .ID = "txtDate" + a;                  
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txtDate);            
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lbl);

                //*******HERE IS: I WANT TO SET EACH TEXTBOX VALUE*******

            }             
}
```

Getting textbox value in save button click event:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   for (int a = 1; a <= int.Parse(ddlUserSelected.SelectedItem.Text); a++)
    {              

      string vvv = Request.Form["ctl00$ctl00$cphcontent$cphmain_main$UserControl$txtDate" + a];  
        //After I send a List each value 
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: then use `txtDate.Text="Your Value"`

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar if I use your method all textbox has same value.

Comment: @BIp then your values should be dynamic

Comment: You need to clarify how the values assigned to the text property should be determined

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar my values also dynamic but I have different data for aech textbox. So my question is how to set these dynamic values in 'textbox.text' ?

Comment: For example When I get textbox value in Placeholder I use: 'Request.Form["ctl00$ctl00$cphcontent$cphmain_main$UserControl$txtDate" + a];'   but When I set value what can I use?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the value before add the TextBox to the placeholder:

```
...
txtDate.Text = "Value";          
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txtDate);            
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

To get values back:

```
for (int i = 0; i < PlaceHolder1.Controls.Count; i++)
{
    Control ctrl = PlaceHolder1.Controls[i];
    if (ctrl is TextBox)
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)ctrl;
        string value = txt.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: But after adding the textbox, it is still accessible using txtDate.Text? If it is still a problem can it be changed to an object array: txtDate[i].text